# Seletor de classe no CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Não estou conseguindo fazer referência a uma `<div>`, que está no meu arquivo index.html, através do meu arquivo .css.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu arquivo index.html:

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="div-address">
            <h3>Endereço 1</h3>
            <p>Endereço 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estou tentando fazer referência à `<div class=""div-address>`, porém, os ajustes que estou fazendo no arquivo .css não estão sendo aplicados a esta `div`.

A referência no meu arquivo .css é dada por:

```
.div-address{
  border: 1px solid;
  font-family: 'Boogaloo', cursive;
}
```

Esta estrutura está implementada logo abaixo da estrutura definida no arquivo .css. Fiz isso pensando que meu estilo poderia sobrescrever algum estilo já existente na estrutura CSS do Bootstrap.

NOTA:

1. Estou usando o framework Bootstrap
2. A estrutura de arquivo está correta (index.html, pasta css, pasta js etc.)
3. Na primeira linha do meu arquivo .css estou importando a font utilizada para o div (`@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo|Yesteryear");`)

Quando eu coloco o estilo ".div-address" no meu arquivo index.html, o estilo é implementado corretamente na `div`. Devo estar cometendo algum erro quando à referência de classes no CSS ou algo está sobrescrevendo meu estilo criado no arquivo .css.

Bom, ainda sou novato em desenvolvimento Web e peço a ajuda dos senhores para solucionar este problema.

Obrigado.

Comment: Estás a incluir esse arquivo `.css` na página com `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="etc...`?

Comment: Olá @Sergio, estou sim "<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">". Minha estrutura de arquivos está correta. Digo isso porque consegui implementar alguns ajustes através do arquivo .css.

Comment: Ok, então estás a mudar o ficheiro do boostrap diretamente/manualmente? ele é estático ou é compilado? tipo de less para css ou stylus para css?

Comment: Olá @Samir, estou implementando meus estilo após todos os estilos definidos no arquivo .css.

Comment: @SamirBraga , quais referências? Poderia ser mais específico? Eu ainda sou novato nesse assunto.

Comment: Seria minha tag `head`? Se for, segue: `<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">`    `</script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o melhor seria colocar todos seus estilos que não façam parte do Bootstrap em um arquivo diferente, e lincá-lo após todos os links `css`. Tal como:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.‌​7.0/css/font-awesome‌​.min.css"    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Aqui vem seu estilo -->
<link href="css/meu-arquivo-de-estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Entendi, não sabia que dava pra fazer isso. Acredito que deva funcionar. Vou tentar aqui e já respondo. Obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou @Samir, muito obrigado! Gostaria de saber apenas se essa é uma boa prática? Perco em desemprenho se eu implementar esta estrutura com mais de um arquivo CSS? Percebi que o meu arquivo pessoal herdou do arquivo css do Bootstrap. Acredito que seja pelo falo de ter sido declarado após o link do css do bootstrap. Mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: @HudsonRodrigues, isso depende de algumas coisas, do tamanho do arquivo, de como as regras são sobrepostas, etc. Sugiro que pesquise sobre performance front-end, é um assunto muito interessante e útil :).